# set Google Calendar to public using Javascript or Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there any way I can make my created calendars public using javascript or google script?
This is my current script to create my calendars

```
function doGet(e) {
var coursename = e.parameter.coursename;
var calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar(coursename);
var output={calendarId:calendar.getId()};
return       ContentService.createTextOutput(Utilities.jsonStringify(output)).
setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I hope you guys can help me! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in the Calendar Service for viewing or changing the sharing settings for calendars. This has been reported as [Issue 1145](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1145). Visit and star the issue in increase attention on it.

There is no support for this via the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) either.

Your only recourse is to use the Calendar UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using the Advanced Calendar service:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar

The code below shows how to use it to give read/write access to a specific user.

```
var calendarId = 'INSERT CALENDAR ID HERE';
  var acl = {
    scope: {
      type: 'user',
      value: 'INSERT EMAIL HERE'
    },
    role: 'writer'
  };
  Calendar.Acl.insert(acl, calendarId);
```